# python - an alternative way to not have repetitive elements print without break command?

Tags: python

First, in my code i'm asked to enter a value from user and the program should place it in the correct orderly position without using the built-in python sort().

My completed code can do this without repetitively inserting the same element, only with the break command. Now i once i remove the break command the number i enter outputs in the list 3 times instead of 1.

Note: we aren't allowed to use the break statement in this Python course

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#List of numbers
myList = [1,9,16,24]

#Enter a number to be placed in the list
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

#For loop to check the placement of entered number
#to compare it and see if it is less than or
#equal to the each and every element in myList
for x in range(0, len(myList)-1):

    if num < myList[x]: 
        myList.insert(x,num)
        #break
    elif num > myList[x]:

        myList.append(num)
        #break
print(myList)
```

ex. output:

```
[-1,-1,-1,1,9,16,24]
```

Comment: Too bad formatting, please remove the quotations

Comment: you could add a new variable like "already_added_to_list". You would initialise this variable with False and set it to True after you inserted the value.  Only insert new values if already_added_to_list is False.

Comment: Is `myList` always sorted?

Comment: ok, so the new variable would be in the for loop but before the if statement and only true when the program checks for the conditions in the  conditional statements?

Comment: Your logic is completely wrong. You insert `num` when it's smaller than a member. Why? What happens when `num` is equal to `mylist[x]` etc. etc.

Comment: I can fix that, not hard to do.

Comment: and actually my logic is correct because it inserts the numbers to their correct position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Have an external condition that you can test at each insertion attempt. If you insert the item, set the condition to false. Then, outside of the loop, if the condition is still true you know the item goes at the end. No breaks involved.

```
myList = [1,9,16,24]

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

condition = True

for index, x in enumerate(myList):
    if condition and num < x:
        myList.insert(index, num)
        condition = False

if condition:
    myList.append(num)

print(myList)
```

Comment: Ok, so in these types of cases, is it proper to use the bool function, depending on which condition would output the result?

Comment: I forgot to add that, If once one of the Conditions is met whether True or False, would the execution of the program come to a close?

Comment: The proper thing to do would be to use a `break`, I'd imagine. What I've done is a nice hack to get you round that restriction.
The program will keep running until it iterates through the whole list - to stop this, once again you'd need a `break` statement.